# Ordering with algebraic types in scala

Tags: scala

I have this:

```
abstract class Issue( ... ) extends Ordered[Issue] { 
  def compare(o : Issue) = due.compare(o.due)
  def render() : String
}

case class Task( ..., subtasks : scala.List[Subtask]) extends Issue( ... ) {
  def render() = ...
}

case class Subtask( ..., parent : String ) extends Issue( ... ) {
  override def compare(o:Subtask) = {
    ... delegate to some field's compare function ...
  }

  def render() = ...

}
```

I want to use

```
val l1 : List[Task] = tasks.sorted
val l2 : List[Subtask] = subtasks.sorted
```

But it does not work:

```
error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[this.Subtask]

starting with method ordered in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits
         ,subtasks.sorted.map(_.render()).mkString(" | ")).mkString(" | ")
```

**How do I write this aglebraic type with different orderings for the individual constructors ?**

Answer (score 2):

In `Subtask` you're not overriding the parent method correctly, because they take different parameter types. Try this:

```
case class Subtask( ..., parent : String ) extends Issue( ... ) {
  override def compare(o: Issue) = o match {
    case x: Subtask => ... // your new comparison
    case x          => super.compare(x)
  }
  ...
}
```

However, when sorting, we need an `Ordering[Issue]`, not an `Ordering[Subtask]`, because the `compare` method takes an `Issue`.

So to sort a `List[Subtype]`, for the compiler to get the correct `Ordering` object, it needs to be typed as a `List[Issue]` rather than `List[Subtask]`.

So add a type annotation where you declare `subtasks`, or upcast it thus when calling:

```
(subtasks: List[Issue]).sorted
```

Comment: Do you know why the compiler doesn't search for contravariant types for typeclass instances?

Comment: @sschaef not quite sure what you mean. `Ordering` is invariant; if it were covariant we wouldn't have this issue, but maybe it's not because of issues mentioned here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/Ordered.html

Comment: Yes, that is what I searched for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the subclass as type parameter to the abstract superclass? Something like this:

```
abstract class Issue[I <: Issue[I]](...) extends Ordered[I] {
  def compare(o: I) = due.compare(o.due)
}

case class Task(...) extends Issue[Task](...)

case class Subtask(...) extends Issue[Subtask](...)
```